Ubuntu 24 stuck on a terminal after restart
Ubuntu 24 was stuck in a terminal screen showing some status. I got access to a terminal by hitting ALT+F2. Then I reinstalled ubuntu-desktop and restarted.
The GUI appears but old installed apps like Chrome and Vlc are gone.
I am not very expert in Linux, please let me know, should I reinstall ubuntu-desktop or I'm doing something wrong?


Is the device working properly now? is the main issue now the softwares that are gone?

Please check that my edits don't deviate your original intent with this question, however you should clarify: you said you're stuck on a terminal in the question's title and you posted a picture of a "stuck terminal" in the question's body, but then you went on explaining that you can boot to a GUI just fine (besides the missing apps), so which one is it?

How did you determine that "old installed apps like Chrome and Vlc are gone." Did you just look for the icon somewhere? Did you check the Desktop Search? Did you check for them in their accustomed place in the filesystem?

If GUI appears after installing ubuntu-desktop, then just reinstall VLC and Chrome.

Actually this is not terminal, but from here I can login terminal buy alt+f2 @kos

Forget those, just tell me why stuck in this view (attached photo).  @user535733

Please edit your question to ask a single, clear, answerable question. You have different questions and conflicting statements peppered all over, and it's not clear to us what's going on or what you are asking. It's up to you to make the question clear.
